# What to do about Geoserver WPS warning" "Could not get a ServiceInfo"?

Tags: geoserver, wps

This is the warning I am getting when I try to use this WPS service from QGIS,
and the processing time is taking too long, but doesn't terminate.

What might be the problem?

```
17 Oct 12:33:25 INFO [geoserver.wps] -
Request: getCapabilities   
    service = WPS   
    baseUrl = http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/   
17 Oct 12:33:31 WARN [geoserver.ows] - Could not get a ServiceInfo for service wps
                                       thus could not check if the service is enabled   
17 Oct 12:33:31 INFO [geoserver.wps] -
Request: describeProcess   
    service = WPS   
    version = 1.0.0   
    baseUrl = http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/   
    identifier[0]:  
        value = gt:VectorToRaster
```

Comment: what happens when you make a getcapabilities request from a browser?

Comment: I get the XML description when i request getcapabilities from browser.

http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?
  service=WPS&
  version=1.0.0&
  request=GetCapabilities

Comment: I have the same problem, these lines appear in the GeoServer logs, the WARN message also happens when making request from browser, or any WPS client.  I suspect a conf file somewhere causing some trouble because it lacks the info it should possess, but I am not sure at all.

Answer (score 2):

As you say that the GetCapabilities response is working, it is unlikely to be an issue with the configuration of the WPS itself in GeoServer.

The following [post on the Hivmr site](http://www.hivmr.com/db/pss9a7p9ssfzfpc97xd39sc879amccpj) discussing an issue with a GeoServer WPS service running on JBOSS tells us that:

> My guess is contention over the thread pool used to execute proceses. When a process executes it does so in a fixed size thread pool. If the thread pool is full (all threads are currently busy executing) the process execution will wait, and block if its a synchronous execution.
>
> So i think what has happened is deadlock, with process "A" waiting on process "B", but "B" waiting for a spot in the thread pool which won't become available until "A" is finished.
>
> By default the size of the thread pool is 2 times the number of cores in the machine. So worst case is 2 threads in size which means two invocations of your process in parallel can produce a deadlock. The thread pool size is configurable so you could increase it, but that is really a bandaid solution. But it could work in conjunction with the control flow module that can limit the overall number of max requests a service can handle. So you just need to make sure that the thread pool size is greater than the max number of WPS execute requests that the server can handle.
>
> server.log where it gets stuck:

...

16:43:42,112 WARN [org.geoserver.ows] (http-executor-threads - 5) **Could not get a ServiceInfo for service wps** thus could not check if the service is enabled

It is possible that this is the same issue as you have encountered, and the solution is to:

**make sure that the thread pool size is greater than the max number of WPS execute requests that the server can handle.**